# How to destruct a few classes in order of depth in C++

Tags: c++

ok so im simplifying my code to the bare minimum so that it isn't a long list to post.. the problem is that the code crashes when I finish the program, i.e., the destructors are called. since the point class is in the ptlist class, and the ptlist in the board class im thinking I have to some how link then when deleting the object in the destructor but it crashes after I get to the if(item != NULL) line in the destructor function of the ptlist... it doesn't enter neither the if clause nor the else clause for some reason.. not sure why.. anyway heres the slimmed down code for my program:

[EDIT] I fixed the code thanks to all of you, it now runs perfectly. thank you all

```
#include <windows.h>  //include all the basics
#include <tchar.h>    //string and other mapping macros
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class point
{
    unsigned x;
    unsigned y;
    int id;
    int type;
    bool covered;
    int maze;

public:
    point(){x = 0; y = 0; id = 0; type = -1; covered = true; maze = 0;}
    ~point(){x = 0; y = 0; id = 0; type = 0; covered = true; maze = 0;}
};

class ptlist
{
    point ** item;
    int length;
    int itemmax;

public:
    ptlist(){item = NULL; length = 0; itemmax = 0;}
    ptlist(int imax);
    ~ptlist();
};

ptlist::ptlist(int imax)
{
    item = new point *[imax];
    length = 0;
    itemmax = imax;
}

ptlist::~ptlist()
{
    delete [] item;
}

class board
{
    ptlist *wall;
    ptlist *path;

public:
    board(){wall = new ptlist(1); path = new ptlist(1);}
    ~board(){delete wall; delete path;}
};
```

Comment: There's some copy-and-waste error at your `point` dtor.

Comment: How does this code even compile? I mean `~board()delete [] wall; delete [] path;}` is not valid syntax you're missing an opening brace. Also you've got a random `*this;` at the end of class point. ALSO, the rule is if you `new` you `delete` if you `new[]` you `delete[]` so you should fix your destructor.

Comment: Use `std::vector`; avoid raw `new` and `delete` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in `~ptlist()` is clearly wrong. You are calling `delete item` when knowing `item` is `NULL`. You should remove the `else` clause.

Also, your constructor for `ptlist(int max)` never creates an array of points for each pointer.

Comment: `delete NULL` is well-defined... (although clearly nonsense in this case)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing that out. But still, that whole clause is completely redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `delete[]` where you shouldn't.

```
wall = new ptlist(1);
delete wall; // NOT delete [] wall
```

Same for `path`.

The rule is when you allocate an array (using `new []`) you deallocate with `delete[]`. When you allocate with `new` you deallocate with `delete`.

Also, you're creating an array of pointers to points or an array of arrays to points. Anyway, you never initialize those pointers but `delete` them later.
You should at least initialize them to `NULL` in the constructor:

```
ptlist::ptlist(int imax)
{
    item = new point *[imax];
    for( int i = 0; i<imax; ++i )
        item[i] = NULL;
    length = 0;
    itemmax = imax;
}
```

And if they are arrays and not individual points, you should delete them with `delete []` in the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to confusing delete and delete[], you don't need to loop deleting all the elements of an array allocated by new[]. Operator delete[] does that for you. See #5.3.5(6). You are doing duplicate frees, which will cause undefined behaviour.